# Java - Why does child does no inherit of parents variables?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, parent-child, parent

Why do I get 0 instead of 1500 when I run this code ?

```
public class Department {
    private double rate = 0.0;

    public Department {
    }

    public getRate(){
        return rate;
    }

    public setRate(){
        rate = 1 + 2;
    }
}

public class Employe extends Department {

    private double salary = 0;

    public Employe {
    }

    public calculateSalary(){
          salary = getRate() * 500;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Department department = New Department();
    department.setRate();

    Employe employe = new Employe();
    System.out.println(employe.calculateSalary());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that code compiles at all? It has quite a few syntax errors, for example you are missing parentheses in your constructor definitions, and you haven't specified any method return types.

Answer (score 0):

You made a `Department`, and then set its `rate` to 3.
You then made an `Employee`, did not set its rate, so it has a `rate` of 0.

When you say `new` you get a brand new object. To get what you want change the code to:

```
Employee employee = New Department();
employee.setRate();
System.out.println(employe.calculateSalary());
```

Your whole code is strange though, a department has employees. An employee is not a kind of department. We use extends to mean that X is a kind of Y.

Answer (score 0):

The child does inherit of parents variable. However, department and employe are different object so they don't share variables. Please try this code:

```
Employe employe = new Employe();
employe.setRate();
System.out.println(employe.calculateSalary());
```